# why new Date() output wrong location?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

On my machine, mac-os, node v0.8.7, why the `GMT+0900`

```
> new Date()
Mon Nov 12 2012 17:23:51 GMT+0800 (CST)
> new Date(553964400000)
Thu Jul 23 1987 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (CST)
>
```

On my server, ubuntu, node v0.8.6, why it is `GMT+0800`

```
> new Date();
Mon Nov 12 2012 17:27:55 GMT+0800 (CST)
> new Date(553964400000)
Wed Jul 22 1987 23:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the timezone set on your machine and your server. The OSX machine might be observing daylight savings time whereas the server might not.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending on the locale setting and date.

On [1987-Jul](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=470&syear=1980), it was DST in Chongqing/Shanghai. So it's UTC+9 for your giving time point.

Unless you give very detailed locale settings, this can't not be explained.

What I'm 100% sure, is the CST thing is wrong, it suppose to be CDT. You may change some other time points to verify my theory.